# AWS S3 SDK: how do I get the filename from the progress callback in a multi file upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

So I'm using the AWS S3 Javascript SDK to upload multiple files. **This code below works well**, but I do have one issue. The `function (evt)` for progress is called asynchronously and I cannot get which filename it was called for. `evt` does not include filename. Is there a way to know?

How do I output the filename to console (where I show the `>>> I NEED THE FILENAME HERE <<<`)

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (files[i]) {
            var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
            bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                console.log("Uploaded  "  + >>> I NEED THE FILENAME HERE <<< + " " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
            }).send(function(err, data) {
                //alert("File uploaded successfully -- " + err);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

evt.key -> should give the file name that is being uploaded...!!!

[image: Result of Evt]

**Edited:**

here is the full code I am using for the managed upload

```
app.post('/uploadLargeFile',upload.array('file', 20),function(req,res){

    console.log("received File")
    var file = req.files;
    for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
        var file = req.files[i];
        uploadLargeFiles(file);
    }
})

function uploadLargeFiles(file){
    var params={
        ACL :'public-read',
        Body : new Buffer(file.buffer),
        Bucket:'ascendon1',
        ContentType:file.mimetype,
        Key:file.originalname
    }
    var managedUpload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
        params:params
    });
    managedUpload.on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
        console.log(progress);
    });

    managedUpload.send(function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
    });

}
```

Comment: It would seem `key` is not part of `evt`. When I change to  `console.log("Uploaded  "  + evt.key + " " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');`  I get `undefined` - and an exmaple output is `Uploaded  undefined 64%`

Comment: is the file being uploaded correctly to the bucket ?

Comment: Yes. all files get there correctly after the upload

Comment: What version of the AWS S3 Javascript SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.230.1 version

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use that version (used older one) and also `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload` instead of just `bucket.upload`

Comment: Yep. It seems updating the version to 2.230.1 got me the `evt.key` working. Thanks.